Return the match that has the best score after selecting the matches with the highest hit value
I posted an earlier question which I got a nice solution to using awk. But I ran into a new issue and realized I need to extract matches that have the best score if I have multiple top matches.
My problem

Return the line for the ASV that has the highest Hit value. But make sure this is a summed total hit (because there are identical lineages that can show up multiple times for an ASV).

However, there are many cases where multiple lineages will have identical top total hits. In this case, return the line that has the lowest e-value from the evalue column.

Again, the e-value can also be identical. In this case, then check the perc_identity and return the match with the highest percent identity value.

If everything is identical (total Hits, evalue, and percent identity), return phrase stating there is a tie.


Snippet of my hitcounts.csv file:
ASV Perc_Identity   Evalue  Kingdom Phylum  Class   Order   Family  Genus   Hits
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc    90.667  3.81E-47    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Megachilidae    Megachile   3
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc    89.796  8.24E-44    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Megachilidae    Osmia   4
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc    95.652  1.40E-31    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Halictidae  Dufourea    1
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc    86.861  1.40E-31    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Halictidae  Megalopta   2
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de    96.599  1.73E-60    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Zygnemophyceae  Desmidiales Closteriaceae   Closterium  1
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de    96.575  6.24E-60    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Zygnemophyceae  Desmidiales Closteriaceae   Closterium  1
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de    95.918  8.07E-59    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Zygnemophyceae  Desmidiales Closteriaceae   Spinoclosterium 1
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de    95.918  8.07E-59    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Zygnemophyceae  Desmidiales Closteriaceae   Closterium  4
523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730    88.776  3.94E-22    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Colletidae  Colletes 4
523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730    89.691  3.05E-23    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Colletidae  Hylaeus 4
69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0    99.329  2.86E-68    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Magnoliopsida   Apiales Apiaceae    Chaerophyllum   1
69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0    99.329  2.86E-68    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Magnoliopsida   Apiales Apiaceae    Sinocarum   1

Desired output as I run the code as a bash script in terminal:
# Scenario 1
> ./max_asv.sh 45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc hitcounts.csv 
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Megachilidae,Osmia,4
    
# Scenario 2
> ./max_asv.sh ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de hitcounts.csv  
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de,Eukaryota,Streptophyta,Zygnemophyceae,Desmidiales,Closteriaceae,Closterium,6
    
# Scenario 3
> ./max_asv.sh madeupASVakasdjlasd hitcounts.csv   
madeupASVakasdjlasd,No matching ASV lines found! 
    
# Scenario 4
> ./max_asv.sh 523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730 hitcounts.csv   
523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Colletidae,Hylaeus,4 
    
# Scenario 5
> ./max_asv.sh 69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0 hitcounts.csv   
69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0,There are 2 lines tied for top [max value = 1]

Another annoying caveat I am trying to deal with is that sometimes I will also have multiple matches that are actually identical lineages if you look at the taxonomy columns (Kingdom to Genus), but they show up individually because they might have slightly different percent identities or e-values. In that case, I've been trying to sum up the Hits column based on just lineage columns to get a total sum count, and then if there are still multiple lines, then I need to check e-value followed by percent identity.
EDITTED So I've combined some different code snippets using chatgpt help and other online awk examples. I almost got it to work but I cannot get it to work for scenario #4.
#!/bin/bash

# Function to process the CSV file and find the best match
max_asv() {
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: max_asv <ASV> <CSV File>"
        return 1
    fi

    local asv="$1"
    local file="$2"

    # Process the CSV file using AWK
    awk -F, -v asv="$asv" '
    BEGIN {
        # Initialize variables
        max_hits = -1
        identical_matches = 0  # To track the number of identical matches
        best_evalue = 1e99     # Very high initial value for evalue comparison
        best_identity = -1     # Very low initial value for identity comparison
    }

    # Process lines that match the specified ASV
    $1 == asv {
        # Combine columns 4-9 to form the lineage
        lineage = $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9
        
        # Sum Hits for identical lineage
        hits[lineage] += $10  # Add Hits (column 10) for identical lineage
        
        # Track all matches for later tie detection
        matches_array[lineage][++matches_array_count[lineage]] = $0
    }

    END {
        # If no ASV matches were found, print a warning
        if (length(matches_array) == 0) {
            printf "%s,No matching ASV lines found!\n", asv
            exit
        }

        # Variables to track the best match
        best_match = ""
        max_hits = -1
        identical_matches = 0
        best_lineage = ""
        best_evalue_in_group = 1e99
        best_identity_in_group = -1

        # First loop: Find the maximum sum of hits
        for (lineage in hits) {
            sum_hits = hits[lineage]  # Get summed Hits for this lineage

            # Check for new max hits
            if (sum_hits > max_hits) {
                max_hits = sum_hits
                best_match = matches_array[lineage][1]  # Assign the first match in the lineage
                best_lineage = lineage
                identical_matches = 1  # Reset identical matches for new max
                best_evalue_in_group = 1e99
                best_identity_in_group = -1
            } else if (sum_hits == max_hits) {
                identical_matches++
            }
        }

        # Now handle tie detection based on Evalue and Percent Identity
        best_match = ""
        best_evalue = 1e99
        best_identity = -1
        best_lineage = ""

        for (lineage in matches_array) {
            for (i = 1; i <= matches_array_count[lineage]; i++) {
                split(matches_array[lineage][i], tmp, ",")
                evalue = tmp[3] + 0  # Parse E-value (column 3)
                percent_identity = tmp[2] + 0  # Parse Percent Identity (column 2)

                # If current match has the same sum hits
                if (hits[lineage] == max_hits) {
                    # Compare based on evalue first (lower is better)
                    if (evalue < best_evalue || 
                        (evalue == best_evalue && percent_identity > best_identity)) {
                        best_evalue = evalue
                        best_identity = percent_identity
                        best_lineage = lineage
                        best_match = matches_array[lineage][i]
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        # If there are multiple identical matches with the highest summed Hits
        if (identical_matches > 1) {
            printf "%s, This ASV has %s lines tied for top [sum hit = %s].\n", asv, identical_matches, max_hits
        } else {
            # If a best match was found, print it with summed Hits
            if (best_match != "") {
                split(best_match, tmp, ",")
                tmp[10] = max_hits  # Replace Hits column with the summed Hits
                # Print ASV, lineage, and total Hits, omitting Percent_Identity and Evalue
                print tmp[1] "," tmp[4] "," tmp[5] "," tmp[6] "," tmp[7] "," tmp[8] "," tmp[9] "," tmp[10]
            } else {
                printf "%s, No matching ASV lines found!.\n", asv
            }
        }
    }
    ' "$file"
}

# Call the function with arguments passed to the script
max_asv "$1" "$2"

This code works for all cases except Scenario #4.
# Scenario 1: Ok
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc,89.796,8.24E-44,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Megachilidae,Osmia,4

# Scenario 2: Ok   
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de,95.918,8.07E-59,Eukaryota,Streptophyta,Zygnemophyceae,Desmidiales,Closteriaceae,Closterium,6

# Scenario 3: Ok
madeupASVakasdjlasd,No matching ASV lines found!

# Scenario 4: WRONG!
523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730, This ASV has 2 lines tied for top [sum hit = 4].

# Scenario 5: Ok
69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0, This ASV has 2 lines tied for top [sum hit = 1].


please explain how If there is no match at all (which does happen to) is possible. Surely for any non-empty list, either all entries must have same number of hits or at least one entry must be have the largest value.

"The code" in your question appears to be an exact copy of the answer to your previous question with no attempt by you to solve the problem you're now asking about. Please try to solve your problems yourself and then ask for help with your attempted solution. If you just want someone to do all the work for you then hire someone, e.g. at upwork.com or similar. To learn awk, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

You explain that you have a CSV input, the code and expected output you show confirms this, but your example input is not CSV. It looks like tab-separated. You explain that you want to print the line(s) with a given criteria but in your expected output 2 columns are missing (Perc_Identity and Evalue). Finally, I cannot reproduce the weird output format you show with your own code. Please edit your question, fix what needs to be and, as asked by @EdMorton, show the code of your best attempt.

you mention, once, the fileASVlist.txt but a) we're not presented with a sample from this file and b) the file is never referenced anywhere else in the question; you'll need to update the question with a sample of the file plus your actual coding attempt(s) that reference the file

for the 2nd set of outputs ... lines 1, 4 and 5 appear to indicate that your input file contains windows/dos line endings (\r\n) hence the reason the 1st character in each line is a space or ]; you'll want to either remove the \r characters (eg, one time run of dos2unix file.name) or update your code to account for the \r characters; as for the 2nd line (2nd set of output) you state the entry for ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de should end in 6 instead of 4 but there is no 6 in the sample input you've provided ... please insure your inputs and outputs match

Right, the 6 is just that I want to sum up matches with identical lineage info first, because technically there are 6 identical genera hits for that ASV. So it would 4+1+1.

@KatherineChau sure, I understand the description but there's nothing in the code you've provided that performs any kind of math on the field contents; the code you've provided merely displays the line with the max value which in this case is 4

Ok I've made the updates using a lot of frankensteining with chatgpt but even with online tutorials for awk for the parsing through multiple scenarios, I cannot get scenario #4 to work.

soooo ... I took a minute to cut-n-paste your sample input into my environment and then edited the file to change what appears to be tabs into commas (to match what your code expects) [NOTE: we shouldn't have to perform this operation just to test your code in our environment]; I then cut-n-pasted your code into a local my_asv.sh file, set +x permissions, and ran your 5 test cases; this code does not generate what you say it does for cases 1,2,4,5; consider reviewing mcve to improve chances of receiving useful help

This isn't exactly what you asked, but perhaps this can give you a clue.  You can do much of what you want just by sorting the data.  So:
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ sort -k1,1 -k 10,10r -k 2,3r  < x.txt | grep -v Evalue | uniq -w 32
45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc    89.796  8.24E-44    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Megachilidae    Osmia   4
523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730    89.691  3.05E-23    Eukaryota   Arthropoda  Insecta Hymenoptera Colletidae  Hylaeus 4
69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0    99.329  2.86E-68    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Magnoliopsida   Apiales Apiaceae    Chaerophyllum   1
ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de    95.918  8.07E-59    Eukaryota   Streptophyta    Zygnemophyceae  Desmidiales Closteriaceae   Closterium  4

I've specified the sort keys as field 1, field 10 descending, and fields 2 and 3 descending.  I then extract the first line from each group.
You could feed that into grep 45b55 to fetch one line at a time.

Here is an incomplete awk script, because I didn't understand the case No. 2
BEGIN {
    FS=","
} 

{
    if ($1 ~ /ASV/){
        header=$0
    }
    else{
        if ($1 in sort_array){
            if ($NF > max){
                max = $NF
                sort_array[$1]=$NF
            }
        }
        else{
            max = 0
            if ($NF > max){
                max = $NF
                sort_array[$1]=$NF
            }
        }
        array[$0]
    }
} 

END {
    print header
    for (key in array)
    {
        split(key, arr, ",")
        
        if ( sort_array[arr[1]] && arr[10] == sort_array[arr[1]] ){
            print key
        }
    }
}

The result:
> awk -f get_max.awk hitcounts.csv                                      
> ASV,Perc_Identity,Evalue,Kingdom,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Hits 
> ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de,95.918,8.07E-59,Eukaryota,Streptophyta,Zygnemophyceae,Desmidiales,Closteriaceae,Closterium,4
> 523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730,88.776,3.94E-22,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Colletidae,Colletes,4
> 69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0,99.329,2.86E-68,Eukaryota,Streptophyta,Magnoliopsida,Apiales,Apiaceae,Sinocarum,1
> 45b552aed13b0b8465b4a38e3e8ff9fc,89.796,8.24E-44,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Megachilidae,Osmia,4                                                          523acf9c870d416b8c2fe803ca314730,89.691,3.05E-23,Eukaryota,Arthropoda,Insecta,Hymenoptera,Colletidae,Hylaeus,4                                                          69863838a7fb9e431a01aaebf8e055f0,99.329,2.86E-68,Eukaryota,Streptophyta,Magnoliopsida,Apiales,Apiaceae,Chaerophyllum,1

As you can see, we have 2 line with the same ASV and Hits, but with different Genus value.
If you can describe better that case we can finish the script as you expect.

Thanks for this! Sorry my explanation wasn't clear. For case number 2 with ASV ff19ffd535c0aefe8575aafcc20265de, in the table there are 4 lines that match this ASV. However, there are 3 lines with identical lineage info from columns 4 to 9 Eukaryota,Stretophyta,Zygnemophyceae,Desmidiales,Closteriaceae,Closterium but these lines have different Hits only because from the BLAST results they have slightly different % identities and e-values. Regardless, this means for this ASV, technically there are 6 total Hits with this exact lineage info. So total hit should be 6.

Also I need my script to call ASVs from a second file, not just summarize the hitcounts.csv file because there are times I have ASVs that don't show up, and I need a way to identify them. So to do that I was calling a random phrase as shown above for the madeupASVakasdjlasd. In my example I was just showing it for specific ASVs to properly show my different scenarios.
